# jq: Use context object as key in query from root

Tags: jq, ansible-inventory

I have a JSON object where the relevant parts are of the form

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "name_1": {
        "ansible_host": "10.0.0.1"
      },
      "name_2": {
        "ansible_host": "10.0.0.2"
      },
      "name_3": {
        "ansible_host": "10.0.0.3"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
  "nodes": {
    "hosts": [
      "name_1",
      "name_2"
    ]
  }
}
```

(the output of `ansible-inventory --list`, for reference).

I would like to use `jq` to produce a list of IPs of the `nodes` hosts by looking up the names in `._meta.hostvars`. In the example, the output should be:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

Note that `10.0.0.3` should not be included because `name_3` is not in the `.nodes.hosts` list. So just doing `jq -r '._meta.hostvars[].ansible_host'` doesn't work.

I've tried `jq '.nodes.hosts[] | ._meta.hostvars[.].ansible_host'` but that fails because `._meta` doesn't scan from the root after the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the root in a variable before changing the context:

```
jq -r '. as $root | .nodes.hosts[] | $root._meta.hostvars[.].ansible_host'
```

But a better solution is to just inline the "hosts" query:

```
jq -r '._meta.hostvars[.nodes.hosts[]].ansible_host'
```